# What is the keyword this referred to in Todo.js? (Backbone tutorial)

Tags: backbone.js

I'm having a hard time understanding the what "this" is referring to in the Todo.js tutorial in Backbone.js. In specific, inside the AppView:

```
initialize: function() {
this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
this.allCheckbox = this.$("#toggle-all")[0];

Todos.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
Todos.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
Todos.bind('all', this.render, this);

this.footer = this.$('footer');
this.main = $('#main');
},
```

So when Todos.bind('add', this.addOne, this) is called, it is binding the view (this.addOne) to the collection ('add'). If so, we assume that the third parameter ("this") is also referencing to the AppView object. Why do we need to have "this" as a third parameter?

Annotated source code: http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` as the third argument is the `this` context to set when the function in the second argument is invoked.

That sounds very confusing, so let me try and break it down. Let's look at this line...

```
Todos.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
```

Had we used this instead...

```
Todos.bind('add', function() { this.$el.text("Hello, world!"); });
```

...we wouldn't need the third argument at all. In this case, the function is called immediately and its `this` is preserved.

However, because we don't want to inline every function, we pass a reference to the function like so...

```
Todos.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
```

This is the same as in your example. When you call a function like `this.addOne()`, its `this` is set to the `this` it was called on.

However, when you pass a reference (don't immediately invoke it), its `this` context is lost, and when invoked, it will be `window`, which isn't what you want.

To prevent this, the third argument is the `this` context to use when the function is invoked.

Internally, Backbone will use [`_.bind()`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to bind it. This is a polyfill for the native [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method on functions.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. Much appreciated. Just one more question, if I may: in the source code, for the addOne function in AppView, what does the parameter "todo" refer to?

Comment: @SeanDokko It's a reference to an instantiated `TodoList` collection.

Comment: But wouldn't there be a conflict since TodoList is not a model, but rather a collection? Wouldn't it make more sense to do:

model: new Model rather than model: todo?